# React 18 - MUI - change font family

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, font-family

I create a theme to change the default font family of `MUI`
But it didn't work.

this is my theme component:

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: ["samim", "vazir"].join(","),
  },
});

export default theme;
```

I use the theme component in my main `app.tsx` to change the font in all parts of my project

```
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
import theme from "./theme/theme";
import Routes from "./routes/Routs";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Routes />;
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

Prepare theme component like below.

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
const theme = createTheme({
   typography: {
    "fontFamily": `"samim", "vazir"`,   
   }
});
```

Then you can apply this in app.js like below.

```
    import theme from "./theme/theme";
    import Routes from "./routes/Routes";
    import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';

    const App = () => (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
         <Routes />;
      </ThemeProvider>
    );

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
``

I guess that issue was belong to ThemeProvider...
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way to change the font family of entire project is using MUI's [CSSBaseline](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-css-baseline/).

theme.ts:

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import samim from "./assets/fonts/samim.ttf";

const theme = createTheme({
   typography: {
    "fontFamily": `"samim", "vazir"`,   
   }, 
   components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: `
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'samim';
          font-style: normal;
          font-display: swap;
          font-weight: 400;
          src: local('samim'), local('samim'), url(${samim}) format('truetype');
          unicodeRange: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF;
        }
      `,
    },
});
```

app.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/styles";
import theme from "./theme/theme";
import Routes from "./routes/Routs";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Routes />;
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: font 'orkeney' is defined but never used. Getting this error when importing it. @Hamed

Answer (score 1):

Created Code sandbox Demo for customizing Material UI Theme,
[Demo Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-easley-q3n8p9?file=/src/App.js)

You would need to use Typography component where you are using text for theme part to take effect

Link from official Docs
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/typography/

Also, you would need to import ThemeProvider from  @mui/material/styles